# jQuery Accordion Sortable Issue - Nested Divs & Nested Header

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'm trying to make a accordion sortable but at the moment it seems flickery compared to the default example.

I believe the issue is related to my nesting structure but I thought that wrapping the content in a div would have solved that.

The actual accordion works fine it just seems to struggle when using the sortable command.

I'm trying to use a styled bar like this for the section headers:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/y5ebikvx9kc9jmu/Screenshot%202014-06-25%2018.09.01.png

Which will then reveal a multi column div content.

The Jquery:

```
// Accordion
$( "#accordion" )
  .accordion({
    header: ".accordion-section",
    collapsible: true,
  })
  .sortable({
    axis: "y",
    handle: ".accordion-order",
    stop: function( event, ui ) {
      // IE doesn't register the blur when sorting
      // so trigger focusout handlers to remove .ui-state-focus
      ui.item.children( ".accordion-order" ).triggerHandler( "focusout" );
    }
  });
```

The HTML

```
<!-- ACCORDION -->
<div id="accordion">

    <!-- ACCORDION SECTION HEADING 1 -->
      <div class="grid dark-grey-bkg accordion-section">
        <span class="accordion-section-number">1</span>
        <span class="accordion-section-title">This is an example title 1</span>
        <span class="accordion-order">^</span>
      </div>
    <!-- /ACCORDION SECTION HEADING -->

    <!-- ACCORDION SECTION CONTENT 1  -->
      <div class="accordion-content">

            <div class="col-8">
                <div>
                    <h3>Content Here</h3>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-4">
                <div>

                    <h3>Content Here</h3>

                    <div>
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <h3>Content Here</h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <h3>Content Here</h3>
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <h3>Content Here</h3>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>

      </div>
    <!-- /ACCORDION SECTION CONTENT 1 -->
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle for your code?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ZNL77/12/ Here is the fiddle - I want the red box to sort the order of the accordion items but you can see it loses its content and is very choppy looking.

The content of the accordions will be more complex but the idea is that the header isnt just a single element it's a div with few spans in it then the content is in a div wrapper and as complex as I like

thanks

Comment: You my sir are a legend! I couldn't see the forest for the trees! many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can wrap the complete header and content inside a div and then set that div as `items` option in `sortable`. That would solve your problem.

Demo:http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/ZNL77/13/

Js:

```
    // Accordion
$("#accordion")
    .accordion({
    header: ".accordion-section",
    collapsible: true,
    heightStyle: 'fill',
})
    .sortable({
    axis: "y",
    items: '.container', //selector which wraps the header and content
    handle: ".accordion-order",
    stop: function (event, ui) {
        // IE doesn't register the blur when sorting
        // so trigger focusout handlers to remove .ui-state-focus
        ui.item.children(".accordion-order").triggerHandler("focusout");
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<!-- ACCORDION -->
<div id="accordion">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="accordion-section"> <span class="accordion-section-number">1</span>
 <span class="accordion-section-title">This is an example title 1</span>
 <span class="accordion-order">^</span>

        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="accordion-content">Example Content</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="accordion-section"> <span class="accordion-section-number">1</span>
 <span class="accordion-section-title">This is an example title 1</span>
 <span class="accordion-order">^</span>

        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="accordion-content">Example Content</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="accordion-section"> <span class="accordion-section-number">1</span>
 <span class="accordion-section-title">This is an example title 1</span>
 <span class="accordion-order">^</span>

        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="accordion-content">Example Content</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Let me know if it solves your issue.